# File explorer crashing in Windows 8 - How to run it again?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I'm having a problem with Windows 8 which is the file explorer is randomly crashing. This used to happen from time to time in Windows 7 too but I could bring back the file explorer by running "explorer.exe" from task manager. I tried to the same thing in Windows 8 but didn't work, is there anything I can do to get the file explorer back to avoid restarting?

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I ran SFC /scanNow and recieved bad new in the form of corrupted files.

Comment: We need a dump to see more. please download [this reg file from my SkyDrive](http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full.reg) and make a double click on the file to import it. If you can't do this, run regedit.exe and import the registry file there! When the Windows Explorer crashes, [Windows Error Reporting Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) creates a dmp file under C:\Localdumps. Please upload the dump file (compressed 7z or RAR to reduce the size) and I take a look at the dump with the Debug

Comment: Could be a bad codec. Try disabling thumbnail generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your Windows by "Windows Update". It will fix your several common issues.

I faced the same problem but after updating Windows it's working fine now. You can update your Windows even if you aren't using the genuine version.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> to bring up the taskmanager. Click `File` in the menu and then `Run Task`. Launch `explorer.exe` from there. It will relaunch explorer the same way as in Windows7. If your explorer does not launch you might have a more serious problem (bad ram, bad disk). But the procedure to relaunch explorer is not different from Windows7.

Comment: well it's not working and i have no bad ram, no bad disk. When this I don't even have the metro UI, and all i'm stuck with is just a blue background and I can between apps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
2. Choose Task Manager
3. Click "More Details"
4. Go to File → "Run new task"
5. Type `explorer` and click OK

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me to fix the problem without actually ending the Windows Explorer task. Just force the frozen windows to close:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
2. Choose **Task Manager**
3. Click arrow next to the Windows Explorer task
4. Right click all the windows that are open under the Explorer and select **End Task**
5. Open the windows back up as normal